# Reducing or eliminating duplicate array entries

Tags: c, arrays, finite-automata, automata

I'd like to eliminate or drastically reduce constant array entries for lookups that involve sets of constants, or next state. This is probably something very simple to do, I just don't know the right structure to use. I'm writing embedded C code where I'm trying to make things very fast, but some of these arrays are getting very large, so I need to strike a balance between code speed and space. I don't have a lot of embedded code experience, and we don't have the expertise at my company.

As a small example, consider three flag variables that determine next state, fEnable, fDone, and fFault. Let's say I encode fEnable as bit 2, fDone as bit 1, and fFault as bit 0. Then I'd have a table like this to determine the state:

```c
const uint8_t NEXT_STATE[] = {
    SEQ_SAME, // 000
    SEQ_PREV, // 001
    SEQ_PREV, // 010
    SEQ_PREV, // 011
    SEQ_SAME, // 100
    SEQ_PREV, // 101
    SEQ_NEXT, // 110
    SEQ_PREV  // 111
};
```

My next state is determined by the encoded input:

```
p->state = NEXT_STATE[ p->encodedInput ];
```

I have a bunch of constant arrays like this for my code, for timing constants and other values (not just next state).

My question is, what's the best way to eliminate redundant entries in a lookup table such as this? For instance, you could use logic reduction and know that if fFault is ever set, you want SEQ_PREV. If not, if fDone is not set, you want SEQ_SAME. For (!fFault)(fDone)(fEnabled) = SEQ_PREV, (!fFault)(fDone)(!fEnabled) = SEQ_NEXT. I can sort of see how you would get there with a constant binary table, but I'm not sure that's the best way to go about it.

As an example of a much larger table, consider this one (sorry about the formatting here):

```c
const enum PowerState_t PWR_TRANSITION_TABLE[16][PWR_NUM_STATES] =
{   // PWR_OFF          PWR_T_ON        PWR_ON          PWR_T_OFF       PWR_FAULT       PWR_CRIT_FAULT
    {PWR_FAULT,         PWR_T_OFF,      PWR_FAULT,      PWR_FAULT,      PWR_FAULT,      PWR_CRIT_FAULT  },          // 0000
    {PWR_FAULT,         PWR_T_ON,       PWR_FAULT,      PWR_T_ON,       PWR_FAULT,      PWR_CRIT_FAULT  },           // 0001
    {PWR_FAULT,         PWR_FAULT,      PWR_FAULT,      PWR_FAULT,      PWR_CRIT_FAULT, PWR_CRIT_FAULT  },  // 0010
    {PWR_FAULT,         PWR_FAULT,      PWR_FAULT,      PWR_FAULT,      PWR_CRIT_FAULT, PWR_CRIT_FAULT  },  // 0011
    {PWR_OFF,           PWR_OFF,        PWR_FAULT,      PWR_OFF,        PWR_OFF,        PWR_OFF         },  // 0100
    {PWR_T_ON,          PWR_T_ON,       PWR_FAULT,      PWR_T_ON,       PWR_FAULT,      PWR_CRIT_FAULT  },  // 0101
    {PWR_FAULT,         PWR_FAULT,      PWR_FAULT,      PWR_FAULT,      PWR_CRIT_FAULT, PWR_CRIT_FAULT  },  // 0110
    {PWR_FAULT,         PWR_FAULT,      PWR_FAULT,      PWR_FAULT,      PWR_CRIT_FAULT, PWR_CRIT_FAULT  },  // 0111
    {PWR_CRIT_FAULT,    PWR_T_OFF,      PWR_T_OFF,      PWR_T_OFF,      PWR_FAULT,      PWR_CRIT_FAULT  },  // 1000
    {PWR_CRIT_FAULT,    PWR_ON,         PWR_ON,         PWR_T_ON,       PWR_FAULT,      PWR_CRIT_FAULT  },  // 1001
    {PWR_CRIT_FAULT,    PWR_FAULT,      PWR_FAULT,      PWR_FAULT,      PWR_CRIT_FAULT,        PWR_CRIT_FAULT  },  // 1010
    {PWR_CRIT_FAULT,    PWR_FAULT,      PWR_FAULT,      PWR_FAULT,      PWR_CRIT_FAULT,        PWR_CRIT_FAULT  },  // 1011
    {PWR_CRIT_FAULT,    PWR_CRIT_FAULT, PWR_CRIT_FAULT, PWR_CRIT_FAULT, PWR_CRIT_FAULT, PWR_CRIT_FAULT  },  // 1100
    {PWR_CRIT_FAULT,    PWR_CRIT_FAULT, PWR_CRIT_FAULT, PWR_CRIT_FAULT, PWR_CRIT_FAULT, PWR_CRIT_FAULT  },  // 1101
    {PWR_CRIT_FAULT,    PWR_CRIT_FAULT, PWR_CRIT_FAULT, PWR_CRIT_FAULT, PWR_CRIT_FAULT, PWR_CRIT_FAULT  },  // 1110
    {PWR_CRIT_FAULT,    PWR_CRIT_FAULT, PWR_CRIT_FAULT, PWR_CRIT_FAULT, PWR_CRIT_FAULT, PWR_CRIT_FAULT  }   // 1111
};
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Your "much larger table" is still only 1kB assuming a 4 byte `int` is used to store a `PowerState`, and could be reduced to 256 bytes if you stored state as a `char`.   So I guess in my mind, your large example doesn't justify the effort to optimize it unless this for an *extremely* resource constrained platform, e.g. a tiny 8-bit MCU.

Comment: Logic reduction along with trying to find "overlapping" sections in the resulting formulas and optimising for low total number of operations seems like a fun way to go, but I fear that this optimisation problem could be really hard (NP?) to solve.

Comment: @Brian It's a 2KB 16-bit MCU and there are lots of these tables because of the functionality required. They've requested new functionality which I can't figure out how to implement without either making the run time much longer or increasing the table sizes by orders of magnitude. So, I'm looking for a better way.

Comment: In that case, fascinating problem and the optimization effort *is* justifiable.  Good luck, and sorry I'm of no real help.

Comment: @Daniel Yes, I know Espresso can reduce logic in a similar way to what I have done and then I could probably use it to traverse binary tables, but I don't know the Espresso algorithm, and this approach seems like a mess. I'm hoping there's a more elegant solution as this seems like it would be a common problem.

Comment: `if(fFault) p->state = SEQ_PREV; else ...`?

Comment: OTOH implementing it as logic will increase program size. I hope you have some spare ROM?